# Next/React js TypeError: cart.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, react, next.js

Galera to criando um componente pra receber os items do meu carinho de compras, no componente que irá receber os items selecionados to colocando um map mas eu recebo esse erro ai em baixo, ainda vou fazer o fetch para pegar os dados da api mas queria saber que erro é esse:

**Server Error
TypeError: cart.map is not a function**

´´´6|
7 |

> 8 |   { cart.map((cartItem, index) => (
> |         ^
> 9 |   ))}
> 10 |
> 11 | ´´
> ´
> Call Stack
> Function.getInitialProps

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

também estou com problemas ao colocar o useState vou colocar aqui as imagens

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem-vinda ao [pt.so], Ana. Quando for adicionar código, coloque-o na pergunta como texto formatado, e não como imagem. E sobre seu problema, você está passando a prop `cart` como uma string `"cart"`, o correto é `cart={cart}`, assim passará a variável `cart`.

Comment: Certo entendi. Obrigada @RafaelTavares mas o erro continua

Comment: O "cardItem" são os itens do array. Você tem que passar ele como props para o componente. Key={index}  cardItem = {cardItem} />

Comment: Tenta editar o post e colocar os códigos.

Comment: cart na imagem1 é um parâmetro na Arrow  Footer e cartItem é uma function de uma lista de item ?

Comment: vou editar aqui, acho que também é porque o array ainda ta vazio, se resolver eu venho editar o post obrigada @RicardodePaula